# Query result in a variable

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Here's what I'm trying to do.  Once the btnDraw is clicked, I want Access to go run the query Test and bring back the results into the string winner.  Then display the result in lblWinner.

```
Private Sub btnDraw_Click()

Dim winner As String

winner = ???????

lblWinner.Caption = winner

End Sub
```

This is the SQL code for the TEST query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Goth Table].representative
FROM [Goth Table]
WHERE ((([Goth Table].[Would you like to be entered in the drawing])=Yes))
ORDER BY Rnd(Int(Now()*id)-Now()*id);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 Winner=
 currentdb.openrecordset("
 SELECT TOP 1 [Goth Table].representative
 FROM [Goth Table]
 WHERE [Goth Table].[Would you like to be entered in the drawing]=Yes
 ORDER BY Rnd(Int(Now()*id)-Now()*id);").fields(0)
 ")
```

I added some line breaks added for readability. You might want to remove those.  I'm also curious about your Order By clause. It's not part of your question, but how does sorting by a random number get you a winner?

Comment: That's how I'm selecting the random record.  Then using the representative from that record to display in lblWinner

Comment: Is there a better way you suggest?

Comment: I tried to vote up your response, but I can't unless I have 15 reputation!

Comment: For the Order By clause, it doesn't need to be that complex. You can just use `Rnd(id)`

Comment: Thanks for trying to up-vote.  Don't forget to green-check the suggested answer that works best for you :)